# Completion unique up to isomorphism

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra

I have a question concerning having a unique completion (up to isomorphism), which I managed to solve partially, but still need some help for finishing.

Namely,

Let $\mathbb P$ = $(P, ≤, . . .)$ be a partial order.  Given $A ⊆ P$, we
say that
$a =$ sup $A$
in case

$a ∈ P$ is the least upper bound of $A$ in $P$, that is

• b ≤ a for every b ∈ A and

• a ≤ c whenever $c ∈ P$ is such that $b ≤ c$,  for every $b ∈ A$.

For a Boolean algebra $B$ and some $A ⊆ B$, sup $A$ may or may not exist in $B$.

We say that $B$ is complete in case sup $A$ exists in $B$ for every $A ⊆ B$.

If $P$ is any
separative partial order, we say that $B$ is a completion of $P$ in case $P$ is a dense
subset of $B$ \ {$0$} and $B$ is a complete Boolean algebra.

Now my question is, how to show that if $B$ and $C$ are both completions of a given separative partial
order $P$, that then $B$ and $C$ are isomorphic.

Okay, it is easy to send $0$ to $0$, unit to unit and put the identity on restriction to $P$ (since $P$ is a subset), but what to do with the rest of elements?

Comment: How is density defined on a Boolean Algebra?

Comment: For example, in this particular case, for any $p \in B$ \ {$0$}, there is some $q \in P$ such that $q \leq p$ @MundronSchmidt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element $a\in B$ is the supremum of the elements in $P$ below it, and by completeness, there is also such an element in $C$, and this gives the isomorphism. Every element in the completion is the join of a subset (in fact, an antichain) of the partial order.

Comment: Okay, but how do you know that such an $a$ is supremum?

Comment: @Eurydice Assume $a^\prime < a$ is an upper bound for the elements in $P$ below $a$ and use separativity on $a \not\leq a^\prime$ to derive a contradiction.